# Simple preg_replace regex that I can't figure out

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a simple regex that will work in preg_replace that will convert any input given it to the following rules:

1) First character must be A-Z or a-z

2) If there is more than 1 character, then the following character(s) must be A-Z, a-z, 0-9 or a space

I need any non-conforming characters to be removed and the resultant string to be returned.

I have this as the regex string:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/
```

I have a little regex experience, so I assume this should work, but when I try a string like:

```
1Athsj294-djs
```

Here:
http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

It is not working, please help. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. Do you want to extract a contiguous substring from the input, or a non-contiguous substring? What is the correct output for your example input, `1Athsj294-djs`?  Is it `Athsj294` or `Athsj294djs`, or something else?

Comment: I would prefer Athsj294djs, but it seems like that is not an option?, therefore Athsj294 will work

Comment: I ended up chaining my accepted answer with a first `preg_replace` with this pattern: `/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/` and this gave me my desired result of `Athsj294djs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/^[^a-z]*([a-z][a-z0-9 ]*).*$/si', '\1', $subject);
```

changes

```
1Athsj294-djs
```

into

```
Athsj294
```

**Explanation:**

```
^            # Start of string
[^a-z]*      # Match (optionally) any characters except ASCII letters
(            # Match and capture...
 [a-z]       #  one ASCII letter
 [a-z0-9 ]*  #  zero or more ASCII letters/digits or spaces
)            # End of capturing group
.*           # Match the rest of the string
$            # Match the end of the string
```

The `/si` modifiers make the regex case-insensitive and allow the dot to match newlines.

Comment: You can capture the "djs" as OP now clarifies they want, by capturing `(.*)` as a second match string, putting it into the result with `\1\2`, then having a second pass which gets rid of nonconforming characters after the initial conforming character: `$result = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '', $result);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex looks alright except you have to remove `^` and `$`

So it should be

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*/', $subject)           // this is for preg_match though
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*/', '$1', '1Athsj294-djs') // for preg_replace
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can capture `preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*/', $string, $matches)` for example and $matches[0] will contain your match. If you want to actually preg_replace that requires lookahead.